# Retraining Inception and Downsampling

Tags: tensorflow

I have followed [this Tensorflow tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cSKfRcEDGUs) on transfer learning with the Inception model using my own dataset of 640x360 images. My question comes in 2 parts

1) My data set conatains 640x360 images. Is the first operation that happens a downsampling to 299x299? I ask because I have a higher res version of the same dataset and I am wondering if training with the higher resolution images will result in different performance (hopefully better)

2) When running the network (using tf.sess.run()) is my input image down-sampled to 299x299?

Note: I have seen the 299x299 resolution stat listed many places online like [this one](http://josephpcohen.com/w/visualizing-cnn-architectures-side-by-side-with-mxnet/) and I am confused at exactly which images its referring to; the initial training dataset images (for Inception I think it was imagenet), the transfer learning dataset (my personal one), the input image when running the CNN, or a combination of the 3.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The inception model will resize your image to 299x299. This can be confirmed by visualizing the tensorflow graph. If you have enough samples to do the transfer learning, the accuracy will be good enough with resizing to 299x299. But if you really want to try out the training with actual resolution, the initial input layers of the graph size needs to be changed